# Factory reset protection (FRP) verification

Tags: security, factory-reset, anti-theft

I have a Samsung phone with Android 6.0.1. I'd like to know  if the FRP is activated. I've been searching on the web for instructions on how to do this. So far I've found instructions requiring the user to actually factory reset the phone. Is there a way to verify if FRP is on (and activate it if not) without having to factory reset the phone?

My phone is secured with a pin number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Samsung support](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/frp/), FRP is automatically enabled when you set up at least one Google account. If you still want to check it's status manually, you will need to enter **Download mode**. To do this:

- turn off your phone and wait about 10 seconds
- hold Volume Down, Home and Power buttons simultaneously until you see a warning
- press Volume Up to continue.

After doing these steps, some text should appear on the screen, including "FRP LOCK" or something like that. There you can check whether protection is enabled or not.

**Important:** to exit download mode, you will need to hold the power button for more than 10 seconds, or if that doesn't help just pull the battery.

---

Please note that FRP can be easily disabled by flashing new ROM without GApps, but if your bootloader is locked that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The factory protection lock should be always enabled as long as you have a password,pin or fingerprint lock on the phone

Comment: Please indicate the source from where you saw this.

Comment: I have seen a from a bit too many sources to be sure exactly which ones but I thought it was just common knowledge that having a password on an android phone automatically enables frp